# strange rgb2gray behavior, results in very deeply hued and contrasted images

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I'm using matlab to capture an image through the webcam, as an rgb image

```
 vid=videoinput('winvideo',1,'YUY2_160x120');
 vid.ReturnedColorSpace='rgb';
 I = getsnapshot(vid);
```

then when I try the following:

```
image(rgb2gray(I))
```

I get something like :
[image]

when I dont rgb2gray, the image looks completely fine and in color...

am I using the wrong function here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like you have a non-grayscale colormap.
Try adding

```
colormap('gray')
```